# Configuring JBoss Web Server to connect to JBoss AS

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, configuration, jboss

I am trying to configure JBoss Web Server to connect to JBoss AS. We have a JBoss Web Server installed and configured on one machine, and JBoss AS installed and configured on another machine. How do i configure my JBoss Web Server so that when i call some url mapped to web server, it will redirect me to actual application deployed on JBoss AS. I tried to search on the web for the same, but couldn't find the specifics. This might be a very simple scenario, but i am novice in configuring it. Can somebody help me over here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on kind of application you have on your JBoss AS server: EJB or web application.

If this is EJB application then create EJB client in your Servlet or JSP page or Servlet Filter or whatever else is used on JBoss Web Server. That client would call EJB component on JBoss AS.

If on JBoss AS server you have also web application, then simply redirect request to the JBoss AS or

Comment: Yes, I have web application on JBoss AS, so I was thinking to redirect request from JBoss Web to JBoss AS. Is there any other alternative in this case? If this is the only alternative, I am using Apache HTTPD to proxypass and proxypassreverse request. Is JBoss Web Server itself provide any capabilities to do that?

Comment: Sure, if you hava Apache in front of JBoss Web then you can use some Apache module to redirect user (e.g. mod_rewrite)